# Comparing results in Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I've created a questionnaire with three categories. Each possible answer in the questionnaire corresponds with one of the categories. I have three admin numeric fields where I add the number of answers selected from each category (fields 121, 122, 123). This part of the form is working. I'd like to compare the totals from these fields to see which is greatest and then return that result to a hidden field (field 126). So far my code is triggering a critical error when I submit the form.

```
add_filter("gform_pre_submission_9", "find_highest_percent"); 
function find_highest_percent ($vata, $pitta, $kapha, $form) { 
$total = 0; 
$vata  = $_POST["input_121"] ; 
$pitta = $_POST["input_122"] ; 
$kapha = $_POST["input_123"] ;

$total = $vata + $pitta + $kapha;
$vata_percent = ($vata / $total) * 100;
$pitta_percent = ($pitta / $total) * 100;
$kapha_percent = ($kapha / $total) * 100;

if (abs($vata - $kapha) <= 10) {
    $result = "Vata-Kapha";
} elseif (abs($vata - $pitta) <= 10) {
    $result = "Vata-Pitta";
} elseif (abs($pitta - $kapha) <= 10) {
    $result = "Pitta-Kapha";
} elseif (abs($vata - $pitta) <= 10 && abs($vata - $kapha) <= 10 && abs($pitta - $kapha) <= 10) {
    $result = "Tri-Doshic";
} else {
    if ($vata > $pitta && $vata > $kapha) {
        $result = "Vata";
    } elseif ($pitta > $vata && $pitta > $kapha) {
        $result = "Pitta";
    } else {
        $result = "Kapha";
    }
}
$_POST["input_126"] = $result;
}
```

I've tested by removing all calculations and simply returning the number 100 but this also triggers the error. Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and include the error? If it's what you mentioned in the comment to the answer by Rochelle, you would need to edit your question, and show us where you are calling the function `find_highest_percent()`. What the error is telling you is that somewhere in your code (possibly `class-wp-hook.php`), that function is being called, but it's not getting all of the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to set the variables to integers?

```
$vata  = (int)$_POST["input_121"] ; 
$pitta = (int)$_POST["input_122"] ; 
$kapha = (int)$_POST["input_123"] ;
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Rochelle. Unfortunately I'm still getting the critical error message.

Comment: Kumara, are you able to see your error log from the site?  That should pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Thanks again Rochelle. The error reads:

"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function find_highest_percent(), 1 passed in /www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 310 and exactly 4 expected in /www/wp-content/themes/lifespa/functions.php:515" 

Line 515 refers to the second line of the function.

Comment: Ah. Remove the space between find_highest_percent and the '('

Comment: Thanks for catching that Rochelle. Unfortunately it's still triggering the critical error.

Comment: Does the error log give you a different error or the same?